# Python - for loop - understanding

Tags: for-loop, python-3.7

I had a problem with a for loop in a python script. 
The problem is meanwhile solved, but I do not understand the necessity of the *comma* that solved the issue.

> this was the faulty for loop:
>
> `variable= (["abc.com", ["", "test"]])`
>      `for a,b in variable:`
>           `print(a,b)`
>
> result:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
>
> ---
>
> this repaired the faulty for-loop:
>
> `variable= (["abc.com", ["", "test"]],)`
>      `for a,b in variable:`
>         `print(a,b)`
>
> result:
>
> abc.com ['', 'test']

Why is this *comma* necessary before the closing bracket?
If I extend the content inside the variable, there is no *comma* necessary at the end.

> without *comma* at the end:
>
> `variable= (["abc.com", ["", "test"]], ["xyz.com", ["", "test2"]])`
>   `for a,b in variable:`
>       `print(a,b)`
>
> result:
>
> abc.com ['', 'test']
>   xyz.com ['', 'test2']
>
> ---
>
> with *comma* at the end:
>
> `variable= (["abc.com", ["", "test"]], ["xyz.com", ["", "test2"]],)`
>   `for a,b in variable:`
>       `print(a,b)`
>
> result:
>
> abc.com ['', 'test']
>   xyz.com ['', 'test2']

Any idea why there is sometimes the last *comma* necessary and sometimes not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment of `variable` in your first example is equivalent to

```
variable = ["abc.com", ["", "test"]]
```

i.e, the value will be a single list; the outer parentheses are redundant. When you loop over that, the first item is the string "abc.com", which won't match `a, b` — there are too many letters. By adding a comma after the list, you turn the expression into a tuple. If you have more than one element, there is already a comma there (after the first element), so you don't need to add another one.

The takeaway is: Parentheses don't make tuples; commas do! Consider the following assignments

```
x = 1   # Integer
x = (1) # Also integer
x = 1,  # One-element tuple
x = (1,) # Also one-element tuple
x = 1,2  # Two-element tuple
```